# Adding a listener on a model in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I currently have a model which is the value of a search box. The search operation is performing perfectly but I also want yet another feature to be performed when the search text is modified. So i wanna add a `listener` or `watch` the model variable. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: @SteveP No.I am not using jquery.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You've got 2 options to cover your use case:

**Use the [ng-change](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngChange) directive**

You can write your input like so:

```
Search: <input ng-model="search.model" ng-change="changeHandler()">
```

where the `changeHandler` is a function defined on a scope.

**Use a watch on a scope**

by writing in your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('search.model', function(newVal, oldVal){
    console.log("Search was changed to:"+newVal);
    $scope.search.watch = newVal;
  });
```

Here is a working plunk illustrating both: http://plnkr.co/edit/Jgb2slcBFzLNKK0JFNyo?p=preview

The difference between the 2 approaches is that `ng-change` will fire only as a result of user's iteractions with an input while `$watch` will fire for any model mutation - triggered from the input control or any other change to the model. So you can preciselly choose on which events you want to react.

Comment: By the way, I understood that this was not a good practice to use `$watch` on `ngModel` values. According to what I read, `$watch` is essentially dedicated to scope listening, while ngChange let us listen to `ngModel` changes ... but maybe I misunderstood.